# Forced trailing slash redirect rule causing strange results

Tags: url-rewriting, jquery-mobile

I've got a .htaccess file that's attempting to force trailing slashes.

I've previously asked this question on Server Fault because I had assumed that it was purely a server question, but I now have a sneaking suspicion that my problem is related to jQuery Mobile.

Please reference [this Server Fault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/341061/trailing-slash-htaccess-rules-causing-full-internal-location-to-be-used) for the .htaccess configuration.

From that question, the result of visiting `http://domain.tld/mobile/hours`is:
`http://domain.tld/var/www/html/mobile/hours/`
where it should be:
`http://domain.tld/mobile/hours/`

The entire site is written in jQuery Mobile, and although my expertise is limited, I think [this bug/drawback](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/trailing-slashes-on-links-24-1-2011) might have something to do with the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely a mod_rewrite issue, not jquery mobile as the var/www/html is a part of the file path for the server which jquery has nothing to do with.

Have you tried setting a rewrite base? Add the following after turning the rewrite engine on

```
RewriteBase /var/www/html/
```

Comment: This isn't what fixed it, but it's close.  I added `RewriteBase /` and a number of other directives and it started working today.  For more detail for anyone landing here from a search see [this short tutorial](http://enarion.net/web/htaccess/trailing-slash/).  I've tried those before, but I must have done something different this time.  I think it might be related to that `RewriteBase /`.

Answer (score 0):

This should have been asked in your original question on ServerFault as the answer has nothing to do with your client library. Instead, you pobably just have to add a `L` (and probably `QSA` too) to the list of flags of your `RewriteRule` like

```
RewriteRule    ^(.+[^/])$      /$1/     [R,L,QSA]
```

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r for more information.

Comment: Making the flags section `[R,L,RSA]` caused no changes in the execution.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I had (mistyped), but I tried it again to be sure. Still not working.